# Are there any specific examples of NLF efforts to manipulate American media?

Tags: cold-war, vietnam-war, media

I often see mentions of National Liberation Front ([NLF](https://www.britannica.com/topic/National-Liberation-Front-political-organization-Vietnam)) efforts to manipulate US media during the [Vietnam War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War), but I can't seem to find any specific examples of this happening. Did I misinterpret its importance or perhaps I am missing something?

[Elements in NLF Triumph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLF_and_PAVN_battle_tactics#Elements_in_NLF/PAVN_triumph)
(7. Shrewd performance on the political and diplomatic fronts)
or [NLF & PAVN Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLF_and_PAVN_strategy,_organization_and_structure#Military_dau_tran%20(*Dich%20van*))

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please look around, eg by taking the [tour]. / Please define your understanding here for "manipulate". Is that supposed to mean just 'influence'? That somewhat loaded term 'manipulate' may fall on a spectrum from getting false numbers, false 'facts' to be reported, suppressing inconvenient news via verdicts, to simply getting glimpses of 'their side of the story' published, despite 'being the enemy'. All sides always use propaganda or spin, within limits this expected, even unavoidable, but all sides may wander off into fabrication, falsehoods, simple lies. Which one here?

Comment: I've got some NFL/PAVN english language propaganda in my bookshelf.  It is poorly printed, inarticulate, internally focused rather than marketting focused, targetted at pre-existing communists in the West, and not targetted at immediate action.  It was at least couple of decades out of date in terms of propaganda when authored.  It shows nothing of the deep understanding or panache of NFL propaganda inside the RVN or PRG.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Thank you! Now that you've clarified, I think 'influence' is the best fit for what I've meant.